# Convert a matrix of zeroes and ones into a colored graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to convert an array like this one int a double-colored graph- where there are zeroes: blue ,where there are ones: white:

[image: Array numbers]

[image: Array as image]

I have tried to do this with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

def plot_islands(matrix):
array=np.matrix
colors=np.where(array==1,plt.figure(figsize=(1,1), width=1, height=1, color='b'),plt.figure((1,1), width=1, height=1, color='b'))
plt.show()
```

python complains that matplotlib has no attribute with color or figure which is very strange.

Comment: could you show more of your code because that can't be all of it right ?

Comment: I have done edit to the post, sorry about the mess

Comment: If you put three backticks (```) before and after the code, stackoverflow takes care of using a code font and coloring. Inside that code area you don't need the 4 extra spaces, just use the standard indentation.

Comment: You could try `plt.imshow(array, interpolation='nearest', cmap='Blues', aspect='auto')` to display your matrix as a colored image.

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not be ideal but it'll do the job:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np


def plot_islands(matrix):
    cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_cmap', ['darkblue', 'white'])
    plt.imshow(X=matrix, cmap=cmap)
    plt.show()
```